# Why PyQt5 give me this TypeError

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

The code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QClipboard, QGuiApplication

text = QClipboard.text(QClipboard.Clipboard)
```

And error information:

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
QClipboard.text(QClipboard.Mode mode=QClipboard.Clipboard): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QClipboard'
QClipboard.text(str, QClipboard.Mode mode=QClipboard.Clipboard) -> (str, str): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QClipboard'
```

I want to write a program that can manage my OS clipboard's data.

How should I deal with the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic python error which has nothing to do with PyQt. The traceback message states:

```
    first argument of unbound method must have type 'QClipboard'
```

This is telling you that `text()` is not a *static* or *class* method, and so it is expecting an instance of `QClipboard` as the first argument (i.e. `self`). So you can't call any of the methods of `QClipboard` directly via the class object - you must use an instance.

The documentation for [QClipboard](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#details) makes it clear how it should be used:

```
   QGuiApplication.clipboard().text()
```

And note that [QGuiApplication.clipboard()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#clipboard) **is** a static method, and so you **can** call it directly on the class object.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QClipboard.html), it seems like the first argument to .text(...) needs to be a unicode object! If you're simply trying to specify the mode, add the (mode=yourmode) keyword to the method call.

Comment: I changed the code like this: 'mode = QClipboard.Clipboard text = QClipboard.text(mode=mode)',but also get the same error